# How to implement caching in Spring in non-component classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I understand that for caching annotations like `@Cacheable`, `@CachePut` to work, they should be used in Spring Component class. But, I have a class that is not a Spring component or service, but I need to implement caching on one of the methods in that class.

```
@CachePut(cacheNames = {"NAME_OF_CACHE"})
public Object addToCache(String cacheKey) {
    // Some computation here
    return response;
}
```

I have a roadblock for converting this class to a component. Objects of this class will be initialized during runtime. Is there any way to implement this functionality?

Comment: Not very easily, no. I'd suggest to refactor your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the caching manually:

1- when you enter the function, check if the cache has the record you want and return it if yes.

2- in the end of the function insert to the cache before you return the result.

Note: you need to have an instance of your cache inside this class which is doable but not preferable.

**On the other hand**, if you have a problem in converting it to component because it needs to be instantiated in the runtime. Spring provides this capability, you just need to check the **[scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)** option.

You can choose the **prototype** scope for your purpose.

Comment: "Note: you need to have an instance of your cache inside this class." which means the cache should be autowired to the class, but since it's not a bean it can't be autowired. After that there are only bad choices.

Comment: That's not totally correct, you can have an instance of the cache without the need to autowire it. you can create a singelton class of your cache class and use the instance of the cache from your target class.

Comment: That's what I meant by bad choices. You're either passing it as a parameter, or injecting it to the class yourself. Both of those are vastly inferior solutions as opposed to refactoring the code and making it a component (as it clearly needs to be).